# BadImageFormatException when trying to use TaskScheduler on Any CPU

Tags: c#, .net, 32bit-64bit, comobject, anycpu

We are trying to change a program from 32-bit to Any CPU.  The program is in C# on .NET 3.5.

We are using Windows Task Scheduler COM wrapper.

The application compiles but when we try to run it on a 64-bit platform we are getting the following error:

> **BadImageFormatException:**
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.TaskScheduler,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b71cab8d8e4499f' or
>   one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an
>   incorrect format.

UPDATE:  We created a new C# project in Any CPU, with TaskScheduler as a Reference, and with a very simple 2-line code (create an instance of TaskSchedulerClass and write a line to the console).  We ran it on the same 64-bit platform, and it worked.  However, the entire application is still not working.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

Since its a COM interop assembly, likely its only 32-bit. You have to keep your project as 32-bit.

Answer (score 0):

your assemly can work only 32-bit, try find x64 version or alternative assembly

Answer (score 0):

You can use WMI to schedule tasks via the standard managed interface to avoid using the COM component which restricts you to running as 32-bit.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394399(v=vs.85).aspx